# How can I hide timebar from YouTubePlayer in PlayerStyle MINIMAL in android?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I want to remove `TimeBar` or `SeekBar` from `youTubePlayer` in android. I use `PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS` for remove  `TimeBar` or `SeekBar` but I want Paused and Play control on `YouTubePlayer` so, I am using `PlayerStyle.MINIMAL` for Paused and Play control on `YouTubePlayer` but I don't want to `Seekbar` I don't know what I can do any suggestion for me. Please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in default PlayerStyle of `YouTubeVideoPlayer`.

You can only use that three default PlayerStyle. [Refer this Link.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle?hl=en)